# R cannot be resolved and is not the field

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm currently learning Android app development, I come to a problem where R cannot be solved, then I try to organize imports everything seem run good so far. But the end of the R was not right, it shows cannot be resolved and is not the field.
For example,

```
R.layout.XXX 
XXX cannot be resolved and is not the field.
```

I had try to clean my sources and restart eclipse, but seems no luck problems still occur. I don't know what happen ? The reason I cause this problem is after I change the name 'blog_web_view.xml' into 'activity_blog_web_view.xml' in the menu folder. Then I having generated errors problems, after that try to clean and finally problem above occurs.

Comment: But it generates the R file, right?

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem in one of your xml files preventing eclipse from rebuilding R. Double-check all of your xml files for errors.

Comment: If it doesn't generate the R file, then you have an XML error.

Comment: also check you don't have invalid chars in your file names

Answer (score 1):

1.Make sure that you have no errors in any of your xml files

2.Make sure that you have inported the correct R file. Delete any imported R files and use Ctrl+O to import another R file

3.Clean the project

Answer (score 1):

Chek your errors while compiling , you have to get a **succesful compilation**.(specially check the error log ,sometimes error ocurrs in the resoures folder:drawables with invalid names, bad xml formats in resources,etc)

Make sure that you have **imported the correct R** file. It should be the one associated with your package name. Review the imports and check the one of R has a format like *com.yourapppackagename.R*

If that doesn´t work then **clean the project** and retry

Answer (score 0):

If you have no XML errors, and even cleaning and building the project doesn't work, you may try, as a last resort, moving all files to another workspace and build it in there. Solved the issue for me a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is some xml files contain error code(maybe it's not display in eclipse), so R class wasn't generated

Answer (score 0):

Try **Project → Clean** And build again. It will be helps.

If Error will be showed again - check your project output path. May be you exclude **gen** folder from build procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project from Eclipse. It works for me always.

From Eclipse select Project from menu bar-> clean option. Select the project from the list where the error appears. Wait till the build completes.

RK 
http://ctrlaltsolve.blogspot.in